# split dataframe column and remove extra variables

Tags: python, python-3.x, dataframe

can you help me in splitting a dataframe shown below

```
metric
{"{'test'}.ab.ov.{'prd'}.gcp.{'392032'}_{rtw}":0.3232,"{'test'}.abv.ov.{'prd'}.gcp.{'392032'}_{rtw}.services.{'API'}":0.3243}
{"{'test'}.aew.dsc.{'prd'}.gcp.{'8329'}_{abc}":0.3232,"{'test'}.aew.dsc.{'prd'}.gcp.{'8329'}_{abc}.services.{'Instance'}":0.932}
{"{'test'}.acd.ard.{'prd'}.gcp.{'892'}_{dxj}":0.3232,"{'test'}.abv.ov.{'prd'}.gcp.{'392032'}_{dxj}.services.{'Big data'}":0.3254}
```

into account and service based on `,` removing `{}, '' and ""`

```
     account                                                      service
test.ab.ov.prd.gcp.392032_rtw:0.3232  test.abv.ov.prd.gcp.392032_rtw.services.API:0.3243
test.aew.dsc.prd.gcp.8329_abc:0.3232  test.aew.dsc.prd.gcp.8329_abc.services.Instance:0.932
test.acd.ard.prd.gcp.892_dxj:0.3232   test.abv.ov.prd.gcp.392032_dxj.services.Big data:0.3254
```

and then joining both the columns into one

```
metric
test.ab.ov.prd.gcp.392032_rtw:0.3232  
test.abv.ov.prd.gcp.392032_rtw.services.API:0.3243
test.aew.dsc.prd.gcp.8329_abc:0.3232  
test.aew.dsc.prd.gcp.8329_abc.services.Instance:0.932    
test.acd.ard.prd.gcp.892_dxj:0.3232   
test.abv.ov.prd.gcp.392032_dxj.services.Big data:0.3254
```

and now again splitting the metric column into 2 based on `:`

```
metric                                               cost
test.ab.ov.prd.gcp.392032_rtw                    0.3232  
test.abv.ov.prd.gcp.392032_rtw.services.API      0.3243
test.aew.dsc.prd.gcp.8329_abc                   0.3232  
test.aew.dsc.prd.gcp.8329_abc.services.Instance  0.932    
test.acd.ard.prd.gcp.892_dxj                    0.3232   
test.abv.ov.prd.gcp.392032_dxj.services.Big data 0.3254
```

Answer (score 0):

use string methods -

```
metric = [{
    "{'test'}.ab.ov.{'prd'}.gcp.{'392032'}_{rtw}": 0.3232,
    "{'test'}.abv.ov.{'prd'}.gcp.{'392032'}_{rtw}.services.{'API'}": 0.3243
}, {
    "{'test'}.aew.dsc.{'prd'}.gcp.{'8329'}_{abc}": 0.3232,
    "{'test'}.aew.dsc.{'prd'}.gcp.{'8329'}_{abc}.services.{'Instance'}": 0.932
}, {
    "{'test'}.acd.ard.{'prd'}.gcp.{'892'}_{dxj}": 0.3232,
    "{'test'}.abv.ov.{'prd'}.gcp.{'392032'}_{dxj}.services.{'Big data'}": 0.3254
}]
df  = pd.DataFrame(metric).transpose().fillna(0).sum(axis=1).reset_index()
df['index'] = df['index'].str.replace(r'{|}|\'','')
df  = df.rename(columns = {'index' : 'metric', 0: ' cost'})
```

**Output -**

```
                                             metric    cost
0                     test.ab.ov.prd.gcp.392032_rtw  0.3232
1       test.abv.ov.prd.gcp.392032_rtw.services.API  0.3243
2                     test.aew.dsc.prd.gcp.8329_abc  0.3232
3   test.aew.dsc.prd.gcp.8329_abc.services.Instance  0.9320
4                      test.acd.ard.prd.gcp.892_dxj  0.3232
5  test.abv.ov.prd.gcp.392032_dxj.services.Big data  0.3254
```

If the metric is a dataframe then you can use -

```
df  = df['metric'].str.split(',', expand=True)
df = df[0].append(df[1]).str.replace(r'{|}|\'','').str.split(':', expand=True).rename(columns = {0:'metric', 1: 'cost'})
df['metric'] = df['metric'].str.strip('"')
```

Comment: metric is a dataframe, I tried converting it to a list using ```metric = df.values.tolist()``` and use it but when i apply ```df  = pd.DataFrame(metric).transpose().fillna(0).sum(axis=1).reset_index()``` df shows    index    0\n0      0  0.0  
@Nk03 can you suggest why it is not working?

Comment: Ohh it's a dataframe. Let me add the updated answer.

Comment: thanks but i already tried split on metric ```df  = df['metric'].str.split(',', expand=True) ``` but it gives output as column=0 and each row as Nan, i thought it is not splitting because , is between {} so might not be able to split the metric. any idea why?